# Magpie issue with HTTP status code

Tags: ee2, rss

In attempting to use the Magpie RSS parser, I'm getting the below errors:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: User Warning
Message: MagpieRSS: Failed to fetch http://careercenter.gammaiotasigma.org/jobs/?display=rss&keywords=&filter=SHOW_AT%3A740037&resultsPerPage=12. 
  (HTTP Error: connection failed (101))
Filename: plugins/pi.magpie.php
Line Number: 1387

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Filename: plugins/pi.magpie.php
Line Number: 104
```

In checking http status codes, 101 =

```
101 Switching Protocols
This means the requester has asked the server to switch protocols and the server is     
acknowledging that it will do so
```

Why would that be considered an http ERROR?

Magpie tag that causes the error:

```
{exp:magpie url="http://careercenter.gammaiotasigma.org/jobs/?display=rss&keywords=&filter=SHOW_AT%3A740037&resultsPerPage=12" limit="12" refresh="720"}
<ul>
    {items}
    <li><a href="{link}">{title}</a><br>
        {description}
    </li>
    {/items}
</ul>
{/exp:magpie}
```

In THE SAME PAGE, I have this feed and it works:

```
{exp:magpie url="http://careers.independentagent.com/jobs?resultsPerPage=12&display=rss" limit="12" refresh="720"}
<ul>
    {items}
    <li><a href="{link}">{title}</a><br>
        {description}
    </li>
    {/items}
</ul>
{/exp:magpie}
```

What am I doing wrong? I ran both through the validator and they are both valid feeds.

Comment: If one of them works and the other doesn't then that would suggest that either Magpie doesn't support multiple requests per page (so try removing the other one to test), or that it doesn't like the filter parameter in your query string: `filter=SHOW_AT%3A740037`. Does that site have any API documentation? How do you know to use that filter and if it's the correct format?

Comment: Incidently the trailing slash after jobs (`jobs/?...`) _shouldn't_ make any difference but if one works and the other doesn't then it's worth matching up to see exactly what part of the query Magpie doesn't like.

Comment: @Ian, if I put in just the one that doesn't work, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Also, removing the `/` didn't help. It still doesn't load, even when it is the only one on the page.

Comment: If I strip down the url to just `.../jobs/?display=rss` it still doesn't work.

Comment: Looking at the http error code I'm getting, it sounds like a server issue to me.

Comment: Where's the documentation that tells you to add this filter: `filter=SHOW_AT%3A740037`? That's the only thing that's different and it contains an [unsafe character](http://perishablepress.com/stop-using-unsafe-characters-in-urls/) so I'd look to question or encode that.

Comment: It seems to respond correctly to a direct request with a 200 response and correct headers so I definitely don't think it's a server issue.

Comment: In the other feed, I'm noticing that magpie isn't parsing it correctly either. The `{link}` and `{title}` tags in the magpie loop put the link and title from the PAGE instead of from the item. I believe this magpie parser is screwed up, too; I have version 1.3.5?

Comment: I'm also trying different feeds and getting the same result: `http://calendar.csus.edu/MasterCalendar/RSSFeeds.aspx?Name=University-Union-Website`

Comment: Personally I wouldn't put too much reliance on Magpie. If you want to grab an RSS/XML feed there are [plenty of options to choose from](http://devot-ee.com/search/results?keywords=rss&addon_version_support=ee2). [Feed Parser](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/feed-parser) could be a good free alternative.

Comment: Just downloaded Feed Parser and it is returning nothing. Even from their own sample feeds.

Comment: Ok, I found the issue and now have it fixed and working for both feeds. Post your comment about Feed Parser as answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I wouldn't put too much reliance on Magpie. It's fine in simple use cases but if you want to grab an RSS/XML feed there are plenty of options to choose from‌​. I would suggest [Feed Parser](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/feed-parser) as a good free alternative.

Comment: This may save a little time. Download from https://bitbucket.org/ajweaver/ajw_feedparser/downloads/